# Error : "Maximum call stack size exceeded" using Vue.js and Leaflet

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, leaflet, vuejs3

I am using Vue.js and Vue Leaflet.
Markers coordinates are updated every few second with an API call.
I would like to add a feature to follow a specific Marker, I try using the max-bounds parameter.

To do that, I register the ID of the marker which is selected for following.
I set a var with the ID of the Marker, then after every data update from API, I'm setting max-bounds.

Currently I am having this error which is happening one the selected Marker ID is set, and happens again at every API call and map refresh :

```
ERROR
Maximum call stack size exceeded
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at new LatLngBounds (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js:1113:24)
    at toLatLngBounds (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js:1296:12)
    at LatLngBounds.extend (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js:1145:51)
    at new LatLngBounds (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js:1120:12)
    at toLatLngBounds (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js:1296:12)
    at LatLngBounds.extend (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js:1145:51)
    at new LatLngBounds (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js:1120:12)
    at toLatLngBounds (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js:1296:12)
    at LatLngBounds.extend (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js:1145:51)
    at new LatLngBounds (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js:1120:12)
```

Here is my code, you can see :

- the followedBalise which contains the selected Marker ID
- the followMarker method which is called from the children BaliseMarker component, it sets the followedBalise and call the setBounds method
- the setBounds method, which is getting the coordinates from the data Arrays. It contains console.logs and all the logs are displayed correctly

```
<template>
  <div class="flex-grow-1">
    <l-map
      :zoom="zoom" 
      :center="center" 
      :options="{ attributionControl: false }" 
      :bounds="bounds"
      :max-bounds="maxBounds">
      <l-tile-layer
      v-for="tileProvider in tileProviders"
      :key="tileProvider.name"
      :name="tileProvider.name"
      :visible="tileProvider.visible"
      :url="tileProvider.url"
      layer-type="base"/>
      <l-control-layers position="topright"></l-control-layers>
      <l-layer-group
          v-for="bGroup in groupsBalises" 
          :key="bGroup.groupId" layer-type="overlay" :name="bGroup.groupName" :visible="true">
              <BaliseMarker
              v-for="balise in bGroup.balises" 
              :key="balise.baliseId"
              :id="balise.baliseId"
              :latitude="balise.lastLatitude" 
              :longitude="balise.lastLongitude" 
              @bId="followMarker"
              />
      </l-layer-group>
    </l-map>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import { LMap, LTileLayer, LControlLayers, LLayerGroup } from "@vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet";
import BaliseMarker from "./BaliseMarker.vue";
import BaliseService from '../../services/balise.service.js'
import FormatHelper from '../../helpers/format.helper.js'


export default {
  components: {
    LMap,
    LTileLayer,
    BaliseMarker,
    LControlLayers,
    LLayerGroup,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      url: 'https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/rastertiles/voyager_labels_under/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png',
      zoom: 7,
      center: [48.9571487, 2.1941876],
      followedBalise: null,
      bounds: [],
      maxBounds: [],
      timer: '',
      groupsBalises: null,
      tileProviders: [
        {
          name: 'Classique',
          visible: true,
          url: 'https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/rastertiles/voyager_labels_under/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png',
        },
        {
          name: 'Satellite',
          visible: false,
          url: 'https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.refreshMap();
    this.timer = setInterval(this.refreshMap, 5000);
  },
  beforeUnmount () {
    this.cancelAutoUpdate();
  },
  methods: {
    followMarker(bId) {
      this.followedBalise = bId;
      this.setBounds();
    },
    setBounds() {
      console.log(this.groupsBalises);
      this.groupsBalises.forEach((group) => {
        console.log('group foreach');
        group.balises.forEach((bElem) => {
          if(bElem.baliseId == this.followedBalise) {
            console.log('balise foreach')
            console.log([bElem.lastLatitude, bElem.lastLongitude])
            this.maxBounds = [bElem.lastLatitude, bElem.lastLongitude];
          }
        });
      });
    },
    refreshMap() {
      BaliseService.getGroupBalisesLastStatus()
      .then(response => {
          this.groupsBalises = FormatHelper.groupsBalisesArrayFormat(response.data).filter(Array);
          if(this.followedBalise !== null) {
            this.setBounds();
          } else {
            console.log("bounds set");
            this.bounds = FormatHelper.getCoords(response.data);
            console.log(this.bounds);
          }
      })
      .catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
      });
    },
    cancelAutoUpdate () {
      clearInterval(this.timer);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I cannot find out what is wrong, the error message looks like it's getting into an infinite loop, but the method is only called once per API call and it only change the maxBounds data, which is not supposed loop on anything.

The maxBounds set is working with no error if I am just setting it with values and not using the setBounds method.

For info, here is the Vue Leaflet bounds setting page : https://vue2-leaflet.netlify.app/examples/set-bounds.html

Answer (score 1):

This code now includes a break statement that will exit the loop once the correct balise is found, thus improving performance by not continuing to loop through unnecessary items. It also ensures that the coordinates are of the correct type before setting them. The console logs have been replaced with an error log that will only trigger if there is an issue with the data, making it more suitable for error tracking in a production environment:

```js
setBounds() {
  let found = false;
  for (const group of this.groupsBalises) {
    for (const balise of group.balises) {
      if (balise.baliseId === this.followedBalise) {
        if (typeof balise.lastLatitude === 'number' && typeof balise.lastLongitude === 'number') {
          this.maxBounds = [balise.lastLatitude, balise.lastLongitude];
        } else {
          console.error('Invalid coordinates for balise:', balise);
        }
        found = true;
        break; // Stop searching once we've found the balise
      }
    }
    if (found) break; // Stop searching through groups if we've found the balise
  }
}
```

The setInterval method is used to repeatedly call refreshMap every 5 seconds. Make sure to clear this interval when the component is unmounted to prevent memory leaks and unexpected behavior.